# Run-time Error '1004' - Method 'Open' of object 'Workbooks' failed

Tags: excel, vba

OK, so far I've uninstalled & re installed Office-2010 3 to 4 times, done hours of research for 3 days with no success. I started getting this error either from Vbscript or Excel VBA, performing the same command that has worked for months. I am not sure what I may have changed, I don't recall changing anything that could cause it but I nailed it down to the `ReadOnly:=True` parameter. I think something may be wrong with the registry... but re-installing should fix it right? It didn't...

Anyways, very simple command that I recorded on Excel 2010. This command **WORKS FINE** and the file opens:

```
Sub Macro1()
     Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\temp\file_9928_131101.xlsx"
End Sub
```

But when I add the *ReadOnly:=True* parameter, it does **NOT WORK**:

```
Sub Macro1()
     Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\temp\file_9928_131101.xlsx", ReadOnly:=True
End Sub
```

This is the returned error ***Run-time error '1004' Method 'Open' of object 'Workbooks' failed***:

When I click Debug, the error is at the only line of code.

Comment: HUH! Typo, sorry. I meant to put ReadOnly:=True. The error comes when I put ReadOnly:=True, not ReadOnly:=only. ReadOnly:=only is a typo that I made while typing the Question on stackoverflow.

Comment: Thanks, Nope, same error.

Comment: Nothing wrong with your code. Ensure that the file exists... Also are you doing this from Excel VBA or VBScript?

Comment: From excel right now. The file exists I bet my life on it! The fist code bit proves that by working. When I add ReadOnly:=True is when the error pops up.

Comment: Ah good find. I just tried and it's giving me a different error: Excel found unreadable content in file 'file_9928_131101.xlsx'. Do you want to recover the contents of this workbook? But I am sure the file is fine!

Comment: And if I click Yes to open it, it says the Workbook cannot be opened or repaired...

Comment: No missing references... just the standard: Visual Basic for Applications, Microsoft Excel 14.0 Object Library, OLE Automation, Microsoft Office 14.0 Object Library

Comment: Seems like a corrupted workbook, not a problem with your code.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys...much appreciated. From my logic I believe it's the registry that's messed up. But I cannot seem to wipe all of it out. Re-installing doesn't work. Any other thoughts?

Comment: Try this with a fresh file. If the file is broken and needs to be repaired, this is not possible with a read-only file.

Comment: The file isn't already open in Excel (or elsewhere), is it?

Comment: OK, Tried with a newly created file. I closed all excel> Open Excel > save blank Workbook as Book1.xlsx > close Book1 > create new Book2 > Record Macro > open Book1.xlsx > stop macro recording > close Book1.xlsx > add ReadOnly:=True to the end of the command, now it is Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\temp\Book1.xlsx", ReadOnly:=True  >> give me the same error when I run the code line!

Comment: This has nothing to do with the registry, no matter how many times you repeat it. The problem is with the file; it's corrupt. When Excel opens it with read/write, it can repair it. When you tell it to open it read-only, it can't (because you've said it can't write to the file).

Comment: Thanks Ken, I hope so! but not the case see my previous entry...

Comment: Thanks David.. The OS is Windows 64-bit and Office is 2010 64-bit.. Not sure what you mean by "open in edit". I opened both Book1.xlsx and file_9928_131101.xlsx  in notepad, it's all gibberish. No indication of encoding.

Comment: Are there any add-ins active in Excel? There might be things that "are going on in the background" when a file is opened. Try disabling all add-ins (File -> Options -> AddIns... will list them all - and there is a "Manage" button at the bottom. You have to disable COM, powerpoint, etc. separately).

Comment: I just recorded the same actions (only difference - I selected "open as read only" from the dialog) and got essentially the same code (different path / file name). It recorded a `ChDir` as well, but commenting that out made no difference. It worked for me - no problem with file corruption or other errors. I am beginning to suspect a conflict with an existing add-in on your machine.

Comment: Yes I checked the Add-ins as well. Furthermore, I ran Excel in safe mode and tried the same code. Same error! it's quite puzzling. Anything else would be appreciated. What would you try next? Excel VBA is fundamental to my work, I need the ReadOnly:=True parameter to function for my automations to continue.

Comment: Look, there is nothing wrong with you code. The code works fine for everyone else. Something else is causing this to happen which makes it off-topic for SO as it's not a programmatic question any longer. I am voting to transfer your question to SuperUser.com where you may be able to get help.

Comment: David, thank you. I tried your command **for %A in ("%windir%\system32*.dll" "%windir%\system32*.ocx") do regsvr32 /s "%A"** But nothing happened. I don't think it found any files. Furthermore I googled your command and found another to try: **for %a in (c:\Windows\System32\*.dll) do regsvr32.exe /s "%a"**. This one found a bunch of them. I rebooted... same problem with Excel continues. Thanks again... I have no idea what the issue is.

Answer (score 6):

The file is corrupted. **Resave it** with another name and **change the name** in the function. Try that it works and after that rename the file as you want to call it.

It worked for me and I had a corrupted file. The read only shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Thanks Helena. But that's a no go, it happens to all excel files. Even brand new ones I create like I mentioned. Files open fine without read-only mode and fine with read-only mode on other computers. It's a local computer problem that I have no idea how to solve.

Answer (score 5):

Putting an answer here for others like myself who have this issue and the normal solutions don't work.

Another potential cause of this is corrupted temporary files. I think it may only apply if the file you are trying to open is on a network drive or other remote host.

Anyway, try wiping your temp folder (as in the one you get to if you type `%temp%` into Windows Explorer) then restarting the computer.

Answer (score 4):

I have had the same issue with an Access file stored in a local OneDrive folder, referencing an Excel file stored in the same local OneDrive folder. The solution was to move all files into a "static" (i.e., not synchronized, not OneDrive) folder.

Thought that this specific case/application might help someone.

Comment: Bingo! Thanks :-). This seems to be an intermittent problem for me. I paused OneDrive and it seems to have sorted it (or I'm being lucky!).

Answer (score 1):

I realise this is late but if you want to open & repair a corrupted workbook automatically use:

```
Set oWB = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\my\file\path.xlsx", CorruptLoad:=XlCorruptLoad.xlRepairFile)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are downloading the file from some external source (eg- email), just open the file directly from the email and then save the file. Try opening the file in macro ...hope it works...it worked for me....:)

Comment: Could you be a bit more concise about the open and save part (or any other) of your solution?

Answer (score 0):

I had a rogue excel process that was running in the background. When I killed it from the task manager the code worked. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I was too, going crazy with Workbook.Open function, getting the weird Open fail error for no obvious reason. My code also did some some copy-pasting after Open function, which seemed to trigger it.

Eventually I found out that turning ScreenUpdating OFF seemed to cause this - keeping ScreenUpdating ON, made things click for me (maybe someone finds this helpful in the future). I'm one of those who tends to switch ScreenUpdating off for all code whenever possible.

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the name of the file and save it once then your problem will be rectify very easy.

ex:- if the file name was Sales Report 1-12-2020 then change it to Sales_report_1-12-2020 or Sales_Report_1

Answer (score -2):

I know I'm answering late on this, but I resolved a similar issue (same error but running excel from a .Net app) by making sure VBA was installed correctly on the target machine.

Control Panel->Programs and Features->Uninstall a Program... find your Office install,  Right-click and select "change" ->Add Remove Features->Office Shared Features->Visual Basic for Applications->Run From My Computer

This did it for me.