# Run-time error '1004': Method 'Open' of object 'Workbooks' failed on Shared Drive

Tags: excel, vba

I have some code in VBA that opens up 2 excel files and does some textual analysis. I successfully debugged it so I know the code runs through all the lines fine. When I go to run my code in the Excel VBA editor it gives me the following error:

```
Run-time error '1004': Method 'Open' of object 'Workbooks' failed
```

I have tried all the proposed solutions from the following post: [Run-time Error '1004' - Method 'Open' of object 'Workbooks' failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19965380/run-time-error-1004-method-open-of-object-workbooks-failed)

None have worked. I have tried clearing the %temp% folder as well as make different copies of the files.

Each time I save the code in a different Excel file it runs, but then crashes the file. Thereafter I start getting the same error as mentioned above when I try to run the code.

The error comes at the last line of the following code:

```
    Dim workbookname1 As String
    Dim workbookname2 As String

    ' this section accesses the excel files and sheets the script will be working with

    workbookname1= "workbookname1.xlsx"
    workbookname2 = "workbookname2.xlsx"

    ' define variables for the the two workbooks
    Dim workbook1 Excel.Workbook
    Dim workbook2 As Excel.Workbook
    Dim worksheet1 As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim workbook2 As Excel.Worksheet

    ' create workbook objects to work with
    Set workbook1= Workbooks.Open(workbookname1)
```

My thinking is that the issue might stem from all these files including the script itself are on a shared drive for work, so nothing is saved locally and nothing can be saved locally.

I'd appreciate any help on this issue as I have been stuck on this problem for quite some time. Thank you

Comment: Is `"workbookname1.xlsx"` the actual text you use? You also need to include the path (ex: `c:\Users\me\Documents\ `)

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad It's not, I use the actual file name, I just kept it confidential. Also do I still need to include he path if the script and file are in the same folder?

Comment: Mock data is fine, I was more interested in knowing if you were using `"workbookname1.xlsx"` or `"c:\Users\me\Documents\workbookname1.xlsx"`. I would always include the path

Comment: Just tried that, and it fixed the problem I was having! Thanks so much! Now the script crashes when I run it, but that's a whole separate issue to figure out