# copy specific data from multiple workbooks

Tags: excel, vba, consolidation

Im new to VBA and I have been trying to create a program to copy specific range from multiple workbooks having data in sheet 2 to a master workbook sheet 2 .

**COPY Condition: the column range will be A20 to AS20 while the row range will depend upon the last cell having data in column R.**

**PASTE Condition: consecutively all copied cells should be pasted with one blank row in between starting from row A20**

**COPY paste condition: range D5 : D18 from source books to the master sheet, on a overlapping manner since the range will be same in all source books.**

I came till the below stage, but no idea to proceed further. Made some corrections but didnt work well.

Prog:

```
    Sub copyDataFromMultipleWorkbooksIntoMaster()

Dim FileItem As Object
Dim oFolder As Object
Dim FSO As Object
Dim BrowseFolder As String

Dim masterBook As Workbook
Dim sourceBook As Workbook

Dim insertRow As Long
Dim copyRow As Long

insertRow = 20
Set masterBook = ThisWorkbook

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

        With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .Title = "Select the folder with source files"
        If Not .Show = 0 Then
            BrowseFolder = .SelectedItems(1)
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False


    Set oFolder = FSO.getfolder(BrowseFolder)

    masterBook.Sheets("Service Order Template").Cells.UnMerge


    For Each FileItem In oFolder.Files

       If FileItem.Name Like "*.xls*" Then



        Workbooks.Open (BrowseFolder & Application.PathSeparator & FileItem.Name)

       Set sourceBook = Workbooks(FileItem.Name)

           With sourceBook.Sheets("Service Order Template")
               .Cells.UnMerge
               copyRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 18).End(xlUp).Row
               Range(.Cells(20, 1), .Cells(copyRow, 45)).Copy Destination:=masterBook.Sheets("Service Order Template").Cells(insertRow, 1)
               Application.CutCopyMode = False
               .Parent.Close SaveChanges:=False
           End With
           insertRow = masterBook.Sheets("Service Order Template").Cells(Rows.Count, 18).End(xlUp).Row + 2
       End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this. See comments in code, if questions - put comments to answer. Hope you find something new. You have to put this code to the Module in Master workbook.

```
Sub copyDataFromMultipleWorkbooksIntoMaster()

Dim FileItem As Object
Dim oFolder As Object
Dim FSO As Object
Dim BrowseFolder As String

Dim masterBook As Workbook
Dim sourceBook As Workbook

Dim insertRow As Long
Dim copyRow As Long

' add variables for blank check
Dim checkRange As Range, r As Range

insertRow = 20
Set masterBook = ThisWorkbook

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

        With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .Title = "Select the folder with source files"
        If Not .Show = 0 Then
            BrowseFolder = .SelectedItems(1)
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False


    Set oFolder = FSO.getfolder(BrowseFolder)

    masterBook.Sheets("Service Order Template").Cells.UnMerge


    For Each FileItem In oFolder.Files

       If FileItem.Name Like "*.xls*" Then

        Workbooks.Open (BrowseFolder & Application.PathSeparator & FileItem.Name)

       Set sourceBook = Workbooks(FileItem.Name)

           With sourceBook.Sheets("Service Order Template")
               .Cells.UnMerge
               copyRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 18).End(xlUp).Row
               Range(.Cells(20, 1), .Cells(copyRow, 45)).Copy Destination:=masterBook.Sheets("Service Order Template").Cells(insertRow, 1)

               ' copy additional needed range D5 : D18 from source to range D5 on master
               Range(.Cells(5, 4), .Cells(18, 4)).Copy Destination:=masterBook.Sheets("Service Order Template").Cells(5, 4)

               Application.CutCopyMode = False
               .Parent.Close SaveChanges:=False
          End With     
        masterBook.Sheets("Service Order Template").insertRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 18).End(xlUp).Row + 2
       End If
    Next

    With masterBook.Sheets("Service Order Template")
        ' if you don't need to highlight the whole row - remove the ".EntireRow" part →---→---→----↓
        Range(.Cells(20, 18), .Cells(Rows.Count, 18).End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Interior.Color = vbYellow
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: ----Set sourceBook = Workbooks.Open(FileItem.Name) ' open source book ---- throws error. what exactly should be done here? it says file was moved, renamed, or deleted.

Comment: I've edited the code, missed that, sorry. There should be `Set sourceBook = Workbooks.Open(BrowseFolder & Application.PathSeparator & FileItem.Name)` to specify full path to the file

Comment: I've made another edit, try it. Note, that I have tested the code and it works correct. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19965380/run-time-error-1004-method-open-of-object-workbooks-failed) thread for possible reasons, because the code is proper.

Comment: im getting an error that " we cant do that to a merged cell" ... this is one of the errors i faced previously...

Comment: i have solved that...   could you please help me on my latest comment ...

Comment: That error tells that excel can't do something (you didn't tell on which line this error appears) to merged cells. Look at your files and check where do you have merged cells?

Comment: i usually have merged cells in column K. while the cells can be multiple.... I hope there must be a way for this

Comment: Will there be any data loss if those cell are unmerged?

Comment: no.. if unmerged the cell data if visible in first cell of unmerged version is enough

Comment: @wells I don't actually get what do you want... where to copy from, where to paste.. Edit your original post with the code you achieved by now and add your other requirements. And please note - there is not an order desk here, here is the place where one can help you in your efforts.

Comment: noted. I am just new to this community.. I am learning to use the codes here  and execute it.... but there occurs error.  ill make an edit with my needs. your advises are much appreciated. thanks in advance

Comment: @wells see latest edit. It is based on the updated code you put to your post. Still one not quite clear thing -  `highlight condition: highlight blank row in column R with range "R20:last valid cell"` - does it apply to the master sheet after all copying was done (as I did in my edit)?

Comment: Ill use condition formatting to it. please ignore that part. while running the code i get compile error "end if without block if"

Comment: @wells corrected, my misprint. Regarding highlight - if you don't need it - remove the `With masterBook.Sheets("Service Order Template")        ' if you don't need to highlight the whole row - remove the ".EntireRow" part →---→---→----↓        Range(.Cells(20, 18), .Cells(Rows.Count, 18).End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Interior.Color = vbYellow    End With` block