# Workbook won't open with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook named "Certified Schedule - E&P - Krause & Hall.xlsx" sat in a folder called "Krause & Hall" on our server.

I have a piece of code that looks up the folder and file name based on the vendor, it works for all other vendors but seems to fail with this one. Strangely the file works absolutely fine when manually opened.

I have created a simplified version of the code to test it:

```
Sub Test() 
Dim Subject As Workbook
Dim Vendor As String

Vendor = "Krause & Hall"
Set Subject = Workbooks.Open("\\amres.ameygroup.net\shareddata\ConsRail\IDH2\LFRRS001\WCRData\SystemsDivision\CP5 Programme E&P Framework\4.0 Commercial\4.1 Subcontract Applications, Certificates and Invoices\Contingent Labour Frameworks\" & Vendor & "\Certified Schedule - E&P - " & Vendor & ".xlsx")

End Sub
```

This works fine when Vendor = Vital, but not as above.

I get the "run-time error '1004' method 'open' of object 'workbooks' failed" error code

Comment: Before issuing the `Open`-method, write the full file name into a variable. Dump that variable into the immediate window. Copy this string and try to open the file with Excel. Does this work?

Comment: There are a lot of other questions with this error, ex, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19965380/run-time-error-1004-method-open-of-object-workbooks-failed). What have you tried so far?

Comment: I suspect it's because that goes over 255 characters.

Comment: @Rory: Good catch.

Comment: @Rory i think you've cracked it

Answer (score 0):

It was because the Krause & Hall file path was 260+ characters, but the Vital path was not. Thanks @Rory.